# Torchligh not updating

Tags: update-manager, games

So I bought the Humble Indie Bundle VI containing Torchlight (among others) and installed them via the software centre. A few days later some updates were available in the Update Manager as in this picture.
[image: Screenshot showing update]
Unfortunately, when trying to install it, the following message appears:
[image: Error message]
Which reads as follows:

```
(Reading database ... 425427 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace torchlight 1.0+2012+09+18a-0ubuntu1 (using .../torchlight_1.0+2012+09+26-0ubuntu1_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement torchlight ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/torchlight_1.0+2012+09+26-0ubuntu1_i386.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/opt/torchlight/Torchlight.png', which is also in package torchlight-bin 1.0+2012+09+18a-0ubuntu1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/torchlight_1.0+2012+09+26-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
```

Could anyone help me fix this?

Comment: Clean your `apt` cache then try again.

Comment: I have, it still isn't working. (Well, I ran apt-get clean)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having this problem as well. I installed it from the command line by running `sudo aptitude safe-upgrade` and it installed successfully.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, after running. I had to run apt-get clean first.